# How to use mssql_conn_id in Airflow MsSqlOperator?

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I'm trying to use the MsSqlOperator in my Airflow workflow, but I can't work out how to set the connection string.

I've tried setting mssql_conn_id to be the connection string itself

```
t2 = MsSqlOperator(
  task_id='sql-op',
  mssql_conn_id='sa:password@172.17.0.2',
  sql='use results; insert into airflow value("airflow","out")',
  dag=dag)
```

I get the error

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `sa:password@172.17.0.2` isn't defined
```

so I suppose mssql_conn_id needs to be defined. Somewhere. Any ideas?

I'm able to connect to the MS SQL database using sqlalchemy like this:

```
params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=172.17.0.2;UID=SA;PWD=password")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

conn = engine.connect()
```

so I know the server is up and running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `mssql_conn_id` parameter refers to a [connection](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#connections) entry in your airflow database, not the actual connection URI.

You have a few options for adding a connection:

- UI: under Admin -> Connections
- Command line: use `airflow connections --add --conn-id my_mssql --conn_uri mssql+pyodbc://sa:password@172.17.0.2`
- Environment variable: set `AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MSSQL=mssql+pyodbc://sa:password@172.17.0.2`

Then just reference the `conn_id` in the operator:

```
t2 = MsSqlOperator(
    task_id='sql-op',
    mssql_conn_id='my_mssql',
    sql='use results; insert into airflow value("airflow","out")',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation - my airflow job is now talking to MS SQL!

Comment: Note, depending on your SQL, you may need to set `autocommit=True`. Took me about an hour to discover this!

Comment: Not sure if this was true at the time of the answer, but today the docs say that the the command line version is like this (note the underscore in 'conn_id'):

airflow connections --add --conn_id my_mssql --conn_uri mssql+pyodbc://sa:password@172.17.0.2

Comment: How do you print the output of the sql?

Comment: +1 very helpful, thank you! I wanted to add that as of Airflow 2.0+, the command is slightly different: `airflow connections add my-db-id --conn-uri mssql+pyodbc://username:password@host:port/database?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server`. If you're not sure what `pyodbc` driver you have, run `python -c "import pyodbc; print(pyodbc.drivers())"`. Make sure to substitute spaces in the driver name with `+` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Code Complete

Go in **admin** > **Connection**
and edit **mssql_default**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mssql_operator import MsSqlOperator    

default_arg = {'owner': 'airflow'
              ,'start_date': '2022-01-01'
}

dag = DAG(
    'name_task',
    default_args=default_arg,
    description='description here',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False
)

task = MsSqlOperator(
         task_id='task_test',
         mssql_conn_id='mssql_default',
         sql=f"create table abc (a int)",            
         autocommit=True,
         database='DatabaseGilmar',
         dag=dag
)
```