# Setup airflow - mssql connection without using airflow UI

Tags: sql-server, docker, airflow

I have a working airflow - docker - mssql connection (mssql is in airflow container, and I am able to communicate with mssql by CLI).
I would like to creat a DAG which is able to read a database without using airflow UI.

With a huge help of this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464524/20325057) I changed env. variable(AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MSSQL: mssql+pyodbc://sa:Database2022@localhost,1433) in docker-compose.yaml like this:

```
    ...
        AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
        AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
        AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
        AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MSSQL: mssql+pyodbc://sa:Database2022@localhost,1433
        _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    ...
```

And created a simple DAG like that:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator

from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.now()
}

with DAG("airflow_mssql_test3", schedule='@daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:
    read_mssql = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id='reading_mssql',
        mssql_conn_id='my_mssql',
        # printing first row of the table:
        sql=r"""SELECT TOP 1 FROM stores;""",
    )
```

In PyCharm I get this single line error:

```
WARNING:root:OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
```

I have Windows 10 but it's running in Docker container, so I do not know where the problem is.

At the same time in Airflow (2.4.1) I have this error:

```
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql'
```

which is strange as well as providers and packages are installed.

I am really stuck, and would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This solved my problems before, so I thought if you haven't, this might help: "Have you tried writing a python method to read the mssql db and use PythonOperator?"

Comment: I had a working python - mssql connection by pyodbc. So my first try was PythonOperator, yes. Where the callable was a function with pyodbc connection, and cursor execution with sql command.
I was able to trigger the DAG in that case, but after that process failed due to the missing odbc driver - I guess as mssql in a container, it is not able to see the driver...but it's only a guess

Comment: So which kind of method did you use to read mssql db?

Comment: What I did was connecting MySQL with sqlalchemy & PythonOperator. MySqlOperator has an [example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/system/providers/mysql/example_mysql.py) like this, although I'll assume you've already see it. I feel lost a lot while using airflow, so maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HXppV-UCv0) will fill a gap for you.